# Retract all flags on multiple posts at once

Tags: support, flags, retracted-flags

Is there any way to *retract all flags on a group of posts* at once, or this is not possible and should I retract them one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. In generally, it's not necessary either to *flag* multiple posts for the same reason. For example, if a user is plagiarizing, you don't need to flag all his posts; a custom moderator flag on one post (possible with links to the other plagiarized posts) is enough.

Comment: thank you @Glorfindel, i have 70 post waiting for review, so in this case i need to retract this 70 post one by one, this is really not useful :(

Comment: But the question remains: *why* do you want to retract them? That they take long to process (e.g. flag to close) doesn't mean they're bad and you need to retract them.

Comment: i just think that i make 70 mistake, when i flag this post, any way i will let them thank you @Glorfindel :)